# if $x=(\mathbf{w}^* \mathbf{f})^*$ and $y=\mathbf{e}^* \mathbf{f}$, can we claim that $x$ is independent of $y$ in this specific case?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, independence

Let $\mathbf{w}$, $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{f}$ be three independent complex vectors. Suppose that $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are of unit norm. In addition, we assume that $\mathbf{e}$ is complex gaussian with zero mean and variance $= \sigma^2$.
Now, we define : $x=(\mathbf{w}^* \mathbf{f})^*$ and $y=\mathbf{e}^* \mathbf{f}$, where $(\cdot)^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose.

Can we claim that $x$ and $y$ are independent (complex) random variables? if yes, why?

Comment: Hint: Assume $w$, $e$ and $f$ have dimension two and compute $E(|x|^2|y|^2)$.

Comment: @Did but why $E[|x|^2|y|^2]$ ? I was thinking may be I can try to compute, for dimension $2$, $Cov(x,y)=E[(x-E(x)) (y-E(y))^*]$ which I suppose is equal to $E[xy^*]$. What do you think ?

Comment: What I think is that the computation you propose will not prove anything while the computation I propose will.

Comment: $|x|^2=|w_1f_1^*|^2+|w_2f_2^*|^2+2Re(w_1^*f_1f_2^*w_2)$, $|y|^2=|e_1f_1^*|^2+|e_2f_2^*|^2+2Re(e_1^*f_1f_2^*e_2)$. Thus, for $E[|x|^2|y|^2]$, $E[4Re(w_1^*f_1f_2^*w_2)Re(e_1^*f_1f_2^*e_2)]$ which I think is $0$, and $E[|w_if_i^*|^2|e_jf_j^*|^2]=0$ for $i\neq j$. Is it correct ? and how to continue ?

Comment: @Did Also, I think that since $|w_1f_1^*| |e_1f_1^*|=|w_1| |e_2||f_1|^2$, hence $E[|w_1f_1^*|^2 |e_1f_1^*|^2]=0$ since $\mathbf{e}$, $\mathbf{w}$ anf $\mathbf{f}$ are independent. Therefore $E[|x|^2|y|^2]=0$. It implies that |x| is ind of $|y|$ and thus $x$ is ind. of $y$. Is it right?

Comment: No, not right, and obviously so: if $E(|x|^2|y|^2)=0$ was true, one would have $|x|^2|y|^2=0$ almost surely, that is, $x=y=0$ almost surely. And this ain't so, right?

Comment: I don't think I got your point. I would appreciate if you can give me a complete answer :)

Comment: Which parts of my comment do you fail to get?

Comment: Why you need to calculate $E[|x|^2 |y|^2]$. And in case we calculate it, what do you expect to obtain as an answer, and how you will deduce that $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Comment: One does not need (and I, less than anybody...) to compute $E(|x|^2|y|^2)$, but I say that computing it would allow to answer your question. Obviously, what computing it would yield is that $E(|x|^2|y|^2)\ne E(|x|^2)E(|y|^2)$, *disproving* independence (if one wanted to prove independence, showing that $E(|x|^2|y|^2)=E(|x|^2)E(|y|^2)$ would not help at all). But all these plans assume that you *start computing*...

Comment: @Did let $z=y^*$. We have $E[x]=E[y]=E[z]=0$. Thus, $Cov(x,z)=E[w_1e_1^* |f_1|^2 + w_2 e_2^* |f_2|^2  + w_1 f_1^* e_2^* f_2 + w_2 f_2^* e_1^* f_1]=0$, since the elements of $\mathbf{f}$ are independent, and $\mathbf{e}$, $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are independent. Do you think this is correct ?

Comment: Maybe **six edits** whose only goal is to push your question to the first page are (much more than) enough, don't you think?

Comment: haha :) You are absolutely right!

Comment: If we perform a change of  basis such that $\mathbf{f}=[1,0,\ldots,0]$, so for $N=2$ we get $x=w_1$ and $y=e_1^*$. Since $e_1$ and $w_1$ are independent, we can say that $x$ and $y$ are independent. I would appreciate if someone can tell me if this approach is correct.